# Use JsonConverter to deserialize JToken to bool

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have an odd JSON object I need to deserialize.

```json
{
  "data": {
    "id": 123,
    "permissions": {
      "appName": {
        "data": {
          "1": {
            "2021-08-01": {
              "2020": {
                "isAllowed": {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've gotten most of it to work with a wrapper and nested dictionaries but the final part isn't working as expected. It works fine if I create a class like this, but using it is clunky.

```cs
public class DataWrapper<T>
{
   public T Data { get; set;}
}

public class PermissionValues
{
   public JToken IsAllowed { get; set; }
}
```

`DataWrapper<Dictionary<int, Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<int, PermissionValues>>>>`

I'd like to change JToken to a bool. When I do that and add a JsonConverter

```cs
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    return true; //{} is true but JSON.net parses as null, old was: reader.Value != null;
}
```

I get an error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not convert string
> 'isAllowed' to dictionary key type 'System.Int32'. Create a
> TypeConverter to convert from the string to the key type object. Path
> 'data.permissions.appName.data.1.2021-08-01.2020.isAllowed'

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: What values can isAllowed have in the actual json?

Comment: Are you interested only about the `isAllowed` value or do you need all the fields?

Comment: If it exists as `{}` then it's `true`, otherwise missing is `false`

Comment: Yes, I need the whole object. There is a lot more to it, this is just a simplified snippet

Comment: Empty brackets {} is true? There is no value .. shouldn't it be false? It would be better if you could give example for both true and false in your post.. because the comment is not completely clear

Comment: Yes, {} is true and no `isAllowed` key is false, I've updated the JsonConverter since json.net considers `{}` as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`JToken.ToObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1_1.htm)

```
string json = "{\"data\":{\"id\":123,\"permissions\":{\"appName\":{\"data\":{\"1\":{\"2021-08-01\":{\"2020\":{\"isAllowed\":{}}}}}}}}}";
var jToken= JToken.Parse(json).SelectToken("$.data.permissions.appName");
var result = jToken.ToObject<DataWrapper<Dictionary<int, Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<int, PermissionValues>>>>>();
```

Use the JsonConvertor Attribute on IsAllowed Property.

```
public class DataWrapper<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionValues
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(BoolConverter))]
    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }
}


public class BoolConverter : JsonConverter
{
    //Implement other abstract functions

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader.Value != null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(bool);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using `jToken.ToObject<>` instead of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>` but same error.

Comment: @Supergibbs https://dotnetfiddle.net/aRhM28.. It works for me.. Check the fiddle and let me know if there is anything wrong in terms of interpretation.

Comment: Works for me too, seems like something else is going on in my code to confuse it. Thanks for your help